# How do I find the previous row that contained the same data?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
A1: 1
A2: 2
A3: 2
A4: 1
A5: 4
A6: 6
A7: 1
A8: 9
A9: 1
```

If I'm at A7, what formula can I write to find the previous cell that contained another 1, in this case it'd be A4. I've tried Xlookup but it doesn't look like search mode has an option to search upward from the current location. I'd only be able to find A1.

Any ideas?

Comment: `XMATCH()` may be what you are after depending on your version of Excel (which seems to be MS365 since you mentioned `XLOOKUP()`)? Otherwise there is definately a way using `LOOKUP()`.

Comment: @JvdV This was super helpful and got me a step closer. I used Lookup and the following formula to search upwards: =LOOKUP([@[ SKU]],1/(D4:D18=[@[ SKU]]),F4:F19)

Answer (score 1):

XLOOKUP will do it:

```
=XLOOKUP(1,$A$1:A1,ROW($A$1:A1),"",0,-1)
```

Note: I used row as the return so one can see that it is returning the correct item.

Note 2:  We need to use a variable range reference that references the range in A above the current row, so this goes in B2 and is copied down.  With the  `-1` as the last criterion it will search from the bottom up.

[image]

But if one wants to return the relative row XMATCH is a better fit:

```
=XMATCH(1,$A$1:A1,0,-1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Scott! This solved a huge issue for us. You seem to be the Excel wiz; if you have a second, I have a quick Excel issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68908643/ifs-statement-with-n-a-logical-test-1?noredirect=1#comment121782676_68908643